# Place elements to canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a little game. I will place some `div`-tags into a `canvas`-tag by JavaScript. This is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    init();
});

function init(){
    draw();
}

function draw(){

    var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 31) + 20);
    var cnv = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];

    for (i = 0; i <= number ; i++){

        var div = document.createElement('div');

        //breedte
        var length = Math.round((Math.random() * 31) + 20);
        div.style.height = length + "px";
        div.style.width = length + "px";

        //locattie
        div.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cnv.height - 100))+ "px";
        div.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cnv.width - 100))+ "px";

        //toevoegen
        div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ")";

        cnv.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

```css
canvas{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #898989;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="playarea">
</canvas>
```

So you can see, it displays only a empty `canvas`. Only if I implement the element, I can see the generated `div`-tags. I have also try it replace some properties in the CSS code of my `div`. But it don't work...

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`canvas` isn't intended to encapsulate `div`-s like this. You should try to use native canvas methods like [`fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) for example, [see this MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes)

With a quick example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    init();
});

function init(){
    draw();
}

function draw(){

var number = Math.round((Math.random() * 31) + 20);
var cnv = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
var top = 0;
var left = 0;
var size = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= number ; i++){

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ", " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ")";

    top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cnv.height - 100));
    left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cnv.width - 100));
    size = Math.round((Math.random() * 31) + 20);

    ctx.fillRect(left, top, size, size);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example on how to use `fillRect`? Preferably one that takes OP's code into mind.

Answer (score 2):

Nodes inside a canvas object will only be shown in browsers that doesn't support the canvas element:

```
<canvas>Your browser <em>doesn't</em> support the canvas element!</canvas>
```

If you want to add elements on top of your canvas you could consider adding a wrapper and add the elements to it:

```
<div class="canvas_wrapper">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div class="canvas_child">My added element</div>
</div>
```

And some css like this:

```
.canvas_wrapper { position: relative; }
.canvas_child { position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; }
```